# What makes this approach better than this one?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, big-o

The only difference is the nested for loop in the first one is assigned the value of i+1 instead of just +1(second one). Why is the first one considered better than the second one?

```java
int[] nums = { 3, 2, 4 };
int target = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        int answer = nums[i]+nums[j];
        System.out.println(answer);//answer should be value of target
    }
}
```

```java
int[] nums = { 3, 2, 4 };
int target = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        int answer = nums[i]+nums[j];
        System.out.println(answer);//answer should be value of target
    }
}
```

Comment: Who says it is better? They are computing something different. `int j = i` vs `int j = 2` is a huge difference.

Comment: What is the code trying to accomplish?

Comment: Those two codes are doing different things! how come you say one is better then other?

Comment: Sorry to everyone. Small error first one is supposed to be j=i+1, and second one is j=1. I updated it please see now. Sorry again.

Comment: can you enplane a bit what's the purpose of this program?

Comment: all it does is is sum two numbers in the array to equal the target.

Comment: Given `i = 0`, then `i + 1` would be evaluated to `1`. Hence, they're both equivalent.

Comment: @MCEmperor There is a typo in your code, you call the same version `m1` twice. The output is different

Comment: output first: 5,7,6 / output second: 5,7,4,6,6,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two codes are don't seem accomplishing the same to me. however as you said in the comment I'm trying to figure out.
In terms of run time, in the first code, the `nested for loop` runs `nums.length - (i+1)` times. Here the best case scenario for nested for loop runs `0` times and for the worst case scenario runs`nums.length - 1` times.

```
int[] nums = { 3, 2, 4 };
int target = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        int answer = nums[i]+nums[j];
        System.out.println(answer);//answer should be value of target
    }
}
```

On the other hand in the 2nd code the `nested for loop` runs `nums.length` times. Here the best case and worst case scenario for `nested for loop` are the same which is runs `nums.length` times.

```
int[] nums = { 3, 2, 4 };
int target = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        int answer = nums[i]+nums[j];
        System.out.println(answer);//answer should be value of target
    }
}
```

Therefore, Based on `best and worst case scenario` we can say that the first code is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations in the first code sample is a sum of sequence: `n - 1, n - 2, ... 1` that is it's a sum of arithmetic progression of `n - 1` elements:

```
S = (1 + n - 1) * (n - 1) / 2 = n * (n - 1) / 2 = (n^2 - n) / 2
```

The number of iterations in the second code sample is `n * (n - 1) = n^2 - n`, that is, it has twice as much iterations as the first one.

However, when estimating complexity (big-O), the constant values such as 2 and expressions of lower order are omitted, thus in both cases `O(N) = N^2`.